# jQuery ".closest" doesn't work

Tags: jquery, slide, closest

I'm recently doing some adjustments to a template. 
It has this kind of FAQ-section where you click on a question and the answer slides down/shows-

Unfortunately this seems broken. 
So I thought I could add some jquery to the footer.tpl.
This basically works - but it still needs some adjustments.

I thought using `.closest()` would be the correct choice but...naaa :/
If I leave it out, it runs, but then every `li` does react.
What should I use instead, so only the "closest" `li` shows/hides?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion_current").click(function(){
        $.closest(".accordion_content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<ul class="list-accordion">
 <li>
     <h3 class="accordion_current">Anfahrt & Messeplan</h3>
     <ul class="accordion_content">
  <li>
  <p>test</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
 </li>
        <li>
     <h3 class="accordion_current">Anfahrt & Messeplan</h3>
     <ul class="accordion_content">
         <li>
         <p>test</p>
                </li>
     </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `closest`, you need `next`. With `closest` you will find parents of the element, but you want to look for a sibling.

And note that you have to use `$(this)` and not just `$`.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".accordion_current").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".accordion_content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-accordion">
  <li>
    <h3 class="accordion_current">Anfahrt & Messeplan</h3>
    <ul class="accordion_content">
      <li>
        <p>test</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="accordion_current">Anfahrt & Messeplan</h3>
    <ul class="accordion_content">
      <li>
        <p>test</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks -that's exactly what I was looking for (: